# The Art of Computer Programming (2nd ed.): Mathematical Induction

Tags: induction

In 1.2.1 Mathematical Induction section, Knuth presents mathematical induction as a two steps process to prove that P(n) is true for all positive integers n:

> a) Give a proof that P(1) is true;
>
> b) Give a proof that "if all P(1), P(2),..., P(n) are true, then P(n+1) is also true";

I have serious doubt about that. Indeed, I believe that point b) should be:

b) Give a proof that "if P(n) is true, then P(n+1) is also true". The major difference here is that you are only assuming that P(n) is true, not P(n-1), etc.

Or, at least, we should prove that P(1)...P(n) is true before proving P(n) => P(n+1).

However, these books are old and have been read by many people (most of them being much more clever than I am^^).

**So what is my confusion here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement and the one in Knut's book are equivalent. The latter is also known as [complete induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_%28mathematics%29#Complete_induction). The difference is in the inductive hypothesis: while usually you assume that $P(n)$ is true to prove that $P(n+1)$ is true, complete induction tells you that you can assume more, i.e. that $P(m)$ is true for all $m\leq n$ to prove that $P(n+1)$ is true.

To see the equivalence, simply let $Q(n)$ be the property "$P(m)$ holds for all $0\leq m \leq n$". Then by "usual" induction if $Q(n+1)$ holds when we assume that $Q(n)$ does, then $Q(n)$ holds $\forall n\in \Bbb N$.

---

Let's examine the example @Korchkidu provided in the comments:

Given $a\in \Bbb N$, let $P_a(n)$ be the property "$a^n=1$", and let $Q_a(n)$ be the property "$a^m=1$ for all $0\leq m \leq n$". We wish to use the fact that $a^n=a^{n-m}a^m$ for every $0\leq m\leq n$ to prove that $P_a(n)$ holds for every $n\in\Bbb N$. Observe, though, that to construct an inductive argument we actually need to use $0<m<n$, since otherwise we have the identities $a^n=a^na^0$ and $a^n=a^0a^n$.

- By usual induction we would prove a base case and then prove that $P_a(n+1)$ holds if $P_a(n)$ does. Then by our previous remark $n=0$ doesn't actually provide a useful base case. So we need to prove $P_a(1)$, too, before we use the inductive hypothesis.
- Similarly, to prove $Q_a(n+1)$ by assuming $Q_a(n)$, by the same remark we need to prove the base case $Q_a(1)$.

Comment: Yes, but in complete induction, should you not prove P(1)...P(n) first?

Comment: @Korchkidu No, you assume that by hypothesis.

Comment: $P(1)$, your initial hypothesis, is an instance of $P(1), ..., P(n)$ where $n=1$.

Comment: @arbautjc Sure. Edited to reflect your comment.

Comment: @A.P. It was just for Korchkidu to make it clearer ;-)

Comment: So what's wrong in: P(n): for all a, a^(n-1)=1. P(1): a^0, OK. Suppose P(1)..P(n) OK. P(n+1): a^((n+1)-1) = a^(n-1) x a^(1) = 1.

Comment: If $a=1$, there is nothing wrong. If $a \neq 1$, please tell us how you can write $a^{n-1} \cdot a^1 = 1$ ?

Comment: @Korchkidu I see what you mean now. I just showed you how to prove that $P(n+1)$ holds if $P(m)$ does for every $0\leq m \leq n$. To prove that it is actually true, indeed you have to show that your hypothesis is true.

Comment: @arbautjc: because we supposed that P(1)..P(n) is true. In particular, P(2) implies that a^1 = 1 and P(n) implies that a^(n-1) = 1.

Comment: @A.P.: so, I also have to prove P(1)..P(n) while proving P(n+1) => P(n). Right?

Comment: But you only proved P(1), and your n -> n+1 step is wrong. Thus you have nothing except P(1).

Comment: @arbautjc: no, based on my hypothesis that P(1)..P(n) is true, P(n+1) is also true. My hypothesis is wrong. That's why I believe that we should also prove P(1)..P(n).

Comment: But to use the fact that $n \geq 2$ in your hypothesis, you must have already proved it in a case where $n \geq 2$. But you have only $P(1)$. It's the usual case where one asks too much from the recursion hypothesis.

Comment: @arbautjc: this is exactly what I asked in my question actually. To  use such an hypothesis P(1)..P(n) is true, I must prove it first. Right? And why n > 1 ? n > 0 is sufficient right?

Comment: You must *not* prove P(1)...P(n) in the general case to use recursion, it's recursion that will give you that. But you must prove an initial case, $n_0$ (which $n_0$, that depends), *and* you must prove $(n \geq n_0 \wedge P(1)...P(n)) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$. If, in this step, you use the fact that $n > n_0$, you are obviously wrong, becasue you have not that in your recursion initialization.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7927/discussion-between-korchkidu-and-arbautjc)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the explanations! It is much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

I think that he presents strong or complete induction, whereas your definition is that of regular (weak?) induction.

Comment: Yes, but in complete induction, should you not prove P(1)...P(n) first?

Comment: @Korchkidu: No: they are your induction hypothesis, just as $P(n)$ is your induction hypothesis in the form of induction that you have in mind.